# How to match and insert new table column to a previous database column

Tags: mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPCCx.jpg

Above is the image of what I am working with.

I need to insert the Styletype column so that the StyleYype matches up with the StyleCode column.

Answer (score 0):

seems you need  update  based on join

```
update table1
inner join table2 ON table2.style = table1.styleCode
set table1.styleType = table2,styleType
```